# How to decode polyline from HERE Routing API 8?

Tags: here-api, abap, geo, heremaps

In ABAP, we need to fetch detailed route from HERE API `https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&origin=21.11336,39.21516&destination=21.52779,39.25381&return=polyline&app_id={APPID}&apiKey={APIKEY}`.

This API returns polyline which we need to decode to get GeoCordinates. We tried to decode using the algorithm given at https://github.com/heremaps/flexible-polyline, but it does not provide correct coordinates.

Can I get exact algorithm that HERE is using to encode polyline, so that to decode polyline in ABAP?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "does not provide correct coordinates"? Can you show us 1. an example of a polyline, 2. what you would expect the coordinate from it to be, 3. your code to decode it and 4. what result you get?

Comment: And no, I am not going to get an API key for that service just so I can answer your question.

Comment: Hi Philipp, 1. Polyline returned from above API is too long to paste here, can you run the same in postman? Use given API "https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&origin=21.11336,39.21516&destination=21.52779,39.25381&return=polyline&app_id=XojHDNMVHM4FGPIIu6cL&apiKey=ZEgW0RSmCa0SOln1SVGE1pD3RvOxf_e7_zsWFy7TC8M" . 2. I want All Geo-cordinates between Origin: 21.11336,39.21516 and Destination: 21.52779,39.25381, these cordinates are in Saudi Arabia, so Geo Cordinates between source and destination should be in Saudi Arabia itself.

Comment: I am not sure that you are allowed to just publish your API key on the Internet. Why not try a simpler test-case before you go with such a complex one? Also, please respond to my inquiries 3 and 4.

Comment: 3. We are using code in JS to decode polyline and later calling JS processor to execute JS code in abap. Code is too long to paste here, but you can check below decode utility provided by Google, as google maps and Here maps are using same algorithm. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility  4. Polyline which you will get using API I provided along with appId and apiKey, paste that polyline in Google polyline utility and the result that it gives, same result we get in abap.

Comment: ApiKey I provided is from Freemium service which I will deactivate in 2 days. So no worries.

Comment: If you solution is in JavaScript, then why did you tag this question as ABAP?

Comment: It is difficult to give you any help as long as you only give us piecemeal information and expect us to puzzle the details together ourselves. It would be much easier to help you if you provided a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Hi Philip, Apology for the inconvinience since I am posting question for the first time in Stackoverflow. This question is abap since we are integrating HERE with Sap using Restful services. To decode the polyline we are using JS code in abap using JS utility. Code is too large so can't paste here. I just need to know, in abap can we convert polyline into Geo cordinates?

Comment: Is there anyway to attach polyline and my code here in stack overflow?

Comment: @philipp jfyi [ mre ] turns into [mre] ;) (no need to use external sites for that...)

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a bit old but found this answer on HERE help pages. An example of an encoded polyline is:

BGo9llkDg_rzZkF0G8LoQ4NoQgP8QoLgKgyB0tB4XoVoLsJ0K4IwWoQsOsJ8LwHoLoGkS0KkN8GsJ0F8GgF4D4DsE0FwHoLUgK8BkIkDkI7B0eTgUT0KjDkhBvCoa7BsT3DwgBvCoVnGg8BjNg4D3D8zB_EsxBjDwgBzFs2BrEgyBvC8V7G8uB7G4wBnBwMkI8BoBnLgP_hEgKz1CsE_nBsJrjD4E1tB

I found the following on developer.here.com page:

"This polyline is encoded using a flexible polyline. You can encode this polyline easily in many major languages using examples available in the flexible polyline repository."

GitHub repo: https://github.com/heremaps/flexible-polyline

"HERE Maps API for Javascript provides wrappers which can do the decoding for you."

I am not using HERE on the client side (even thought it is awesome), I am using some legacy mapping plugin.

I was able to use this code in this file to figure out how to decode the polyline.

https://github.com/heremaps/flexible-polyline/blob/master/javascript/index.js

My code takes the encoded polyline, sends it through the decode method and I end up with a cute object that contains the polyline array as expected.

Below is a screenshot of the console.log of the decoded object pasted above.

[image: Screen shot of console log of object]